# Is there a way to extract a sub pattern from a repeated PatternSequence?

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider the following `Pattern` expression:

```
keysLevel1Pattern={_,
    XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement["h2",{"class"->"level-title"},{x_,XMLElement[_,_,{y_}],_}],_}],_}],
    _,
    XMLElement[_,_,{_,
        PatternSequence[XMLElement[_,_,{_,_,_,_,XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement["h3",{"class"->"course-title"},{_}],_,_,_,_,_}],_,_,_}],_}],
        _]..
    }],
_}:>StringRiffle@StringTrim[{x,y}]->{};
```

If I run it as follows it works fine and is able to capture all the required sub expressions:

```
Cases[pageXML,keysLevel1Pattern,∞]
```

But I want to exact something from each `PatternSequence` that matches and collect it in a list. So I try the following modification:

```
keysLevel1Pattern={_,
    XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement["h2",{"class"->"level-title"},{x_,XMLElement[_,_,{y_}],_}],_}],_}],
    _,
    XMLElement[_,_,{_,
        PatternSequence[XMLElement[_,_,{_,_,_,_,XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement["h3",{"class"->"course-title"},{z_}],_,_,_,_,_}],_,_,_}],_}],
        _]..
    }],
_}:>StringRiffle@StringTrim[{x,y}]->{z};
```

But this doesn't work.

So my question is, is there a way to nicely refer to each `z` that matches in the `PatternSequence` without using nested `Cases`?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the structure is fixed enough, you can capture the entire `PatternSequence` into a single named [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) (`:`), and use [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) (`[[…]]`) with a [`Span`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html)-type (`;;`) part-specification to extract the relevant parts:

```
list = {
   {1, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}},
   {4, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1}},
   {5, {1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 1}}
   };

pat = {x_, {s : PatternSequence[_, _] ..}} :> x -> {s}[[;; ;; 2]];

Cases[list, pat]
(* {1 -> {2, 4, 6}, 4 -> {3, 5, 7}, 5 -> {1, 5, 8}} *)
```

The above extracts every second element from the `Repeated` pattern, i.e. the left element from each `PatternSequence` match.

In your case, the part specification is more complicated, since you have a deeply nested pattern. You can use `Position` to help you find the part specification:

```
Position[Verbatim[z_]]@PatternSequence[XMLElement[_, _, {_, _, _, _, XMLElement[_, _, {_, XMLElement[_, _, {_, XMLElement["h3", {"class" -> "course-title"}, {z_}], _, _, _, _, _}], _, _, _}], _}], _]
(* {{1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1}} *)
```

So your pattern would look like this (keeping in mind that the first `1` above should be `;;;;2`):

```
keysLevel1Pattern={_,
    XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement["h2",{"class"->"level-title"},{x_,XMLElement[_,_,{y_}],_}],_}],_}],
    _,
    XMLElement[_,_,{_,
        z:PatternSequence[XMLElement[_,_,{_,_,_,_,XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement[_,_,{_,XMLElement["h3",{"class"->"course-title"},{_}],_,_,_,_,_}],_,_,_}],_}],
        _]..
    }],
_}:>StringRiffle@StringTrim[{x,y}]->{z}[[;; ;; 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1]];
```